# Which older DTP software has exported these bitmaps?

Tags: export, bitmaps, dtp

There's a lot of such full-page bitmaps ([sample 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etRD4.gif), [sample 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8S2D.gif), [sample 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkgW6.gif)) floating around the data-entry market. Apparently the software that generated these can export the **bitmaps**, but not the **text**, requiring humans to manually type it in again.

It appears to be an older type of software, probably DOS-based, but after some online research I found that older DTP software like QuarkXpress, Pagemaker, MS Publisher, all can export the text directly.

Any ideas which old outdated software or computer system (Mac, IBM, Amiga?) would export such bitmaps?

Comment: Are those samples the original files? If they are the original files were produced in or after 1989 (The GIF format was introduces in 1987, and those files are in GIF89 format).  If you converted the files to get a smaller post, can we have a look at the [first part of ] a real file?

Comment: No I did not convert the files. They are the originals I recived, however they could have been converted by the 1st party.

Comment: Can you verify that with the 1st party? It would be nice to 1) Know there are the originals. 2) The date the files were created on (assuming those are still intact that could limit the time frame a bit more) 3) Any original files names of folder structure.  (If those are use long names then DOS is unlikely. It is allows Capital and small letters to be mixed then the Amiga FFS is more likely, etc etc).